# MVC session timeout with Azure active directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

AAD authentication is implemented in our MVC website. Solution contains website project, webapi project and others.

AAD access token default expiration time is 60 minutes.If user is idle, MVC session is expiring within 20-30 minutes, due to this some times we are unable to get new AAD access token.

Looking for solution to 
1) Extend MVC session timeout value
2) Auto refresh of AAD acces time even user is idle for 1 hour

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look here: [Active Directory Configurable Token Lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

This article gives a pretty good description of Access Tokens, Refresh Tokens, and a new feature we released which will enable you to adjust the token lifetime for your application to be different than what is default in the directory.

The big thing you should take away here is that even though Access Tokens only last for 1 hour, you can use the refresh token, which has a lifetime of 14 days to get a new access token when the current one expires.

You should get a refresh token whenever a user physically signs into your application, and you simply need to harness the token exchange workflow to obtain new access tokens. This process is described here: [Refreshing the Access Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens)

Let me know if this helps you out!

Comment: We are using ADAL 3.x version. We are unable to get refresh token. For more info check http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/13/adal-3-didnt-return-refresh-tokens-for-5-months-and-nobody-noticed/